# What is the easiest way to get a EC2 public dns inside a running instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I'm writing a bash script that needs to use the instance's public dns name. What's the easiest way to obtain it from inside the running instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can fetch data about the running instance from a little http API using curl like this:

```
#/bin/bash
public_name=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-hostname)
echo $public_name
```

Other values you can fetch include:

- ami-id
- hostname
- instance-id
- local-ipv4
- local-hostname
- public-hostname
- public-ipv4

There are more but those are some of the most useful. Things like the SSH keys you specify at instance launch can also be retrieved from there.

Comment: Note that the DNS name for that API is `instance-data.ec2.internal` if you'd prefer to use that.